# How to limit the number of words in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Given the following XML document:

```
<books>
  <book>
   <name>The problem of the ages</name>
  </book>
  <book>
   <name>Filtering the tap</name>
  </book>
  <book>
   <name>Legend of Atlantis</name>
  </book>
</books>
```

I want to take at most 2 words from the name of each book. Words can be assumed as being sequences of whitespace-separated characters. Example of output:

```
<library>
  <record>The problem</record>
  <record>Filtering the</record>
  <record>Legend of</record>
</library>
```

How would I achieve this using a single XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (in 3.0 with expand-text enabled):

```
<xsl:template match="book/name">
  <record>{tokenize(.) => subsequence(1, 2)}</record>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how expand-text affects the output?

Comment: Setting `expand-text="yes"` enables the use of the curly-brace notation, which I always use these days as an alternatiive to `xsl:value-of ` instructioins.